# How do I discern which variables depend on grouping variable?

Tags: r

I want to find variables that have multiple values within a group -- i.e. variables that depend (or do not depend) on the grouping variables.

In other words, for example with a dataframe with information that either

(1) depend on firm (e.g. "industry") or

(2) depend on firm-year (e.g. "annual sales"),

I want to be able to discern which variables are of the kind (1) and which are of the kind (2).

```
sample_df <- 
    data.frame(
        year = rep(2013:2015, 3), 
        firm = rep(c("Disney", "Netflix", "Hulu"), each = 3), 
        infoA = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 3)), 
        infoB = c(c(1:3), rep(2, 6)), 
        infoC = rep(3:1, each = 3)
    )

# year    firm infoA infoB infoC
# 2013  Disney     1     1     3
# 2014  Disney     1     2     3
# 2015  Disney     1     3     3
# 2013 Netflix     1     2     2
# 2014 Netflix     1     2     2
# 2015 Netflix     1     2     2
# 2013    Hulu     2     2     1
# 2014    Hulu     2     2     1
# 2015    Hulu     2     2     1
```

If the grouping variable is 'firm',

(1) columns 'infoA' and 'infoC' do not vary within each group,

(2) while 'year' and 'infoB' would vary within each group,

What would be the simplest way to achieve this division in an environment with many columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function counting number of unique values per group. If there is a variation in the values we return `TRUE` or `FALSE` otherwise.

```
library(dplyr)

check_dependability <- function(data, col1, col2 = NULL) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{col1}}, {{col2}}) %>%
    summarise(across(.fns = ~n_distinct(.) > 1))
}

check_dependability(sample_df, firm)

#  firm    year  infoA infoB infoC
#  <chr>   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 Disney  TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#2 Hulu    TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 Netflix TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE

check_dependability(sample_df, firm, year)

#  firm     year infoA infoB infoC
#  <chr>   <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 Disney   2013 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#2 Disney   2014 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 Disney   2015 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#4 Hulu     2013 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#5 Hulu     2014 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#6 Hulu     2015 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#7 Netflix  2013 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#8 Netflix  2014 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#9 Netflix  2015 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by your groupnig variable and count numer of distinct items, if they are all the same then return 0 else 1

```
res=aggregate(
  subset(sample_df,select=-c(firm)),
  list(sample_df$firm),
  function(x){
    if (length(table(x))==1){
      0
    } else {
      1
    }
  }
)
  Group.1 year infoA infoB infoC
1  Disney    1     0     1     0
2    Hulu    1     0     0     0
3 Netflix    1     0     0     0
```

To find out which columns differ from the grouping variable simply sum by columns

```
colSums(subset(res,select=-c(Group.1)))==0
 year infoA infoB infoC 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Nice +1, or more succinct: `aggregate(cbind(year, infoA, infoB, infoC) ~ firm, sample_df, function(x) ifelse(length(table(x)) == 1, 0, 1))`